# How to add Pairs to a Java Map

Tags: java, networking, client-server, thrift

this is my very first thread on StackOverflow so please be patient!

Starting from a simple thrift service, I want to create a java client/server application, where each node offers one or more services to other nodes in a distributed computing system. I want to start with a simple system where each node is characterized by two strings, "hostname" and "servicename", that identify each from others. I have created this class:

```
class NodePort <Node, integer> {
  private Node node;
  private int port;

  NodePort(Node node, int port) {
    this.node = node;
    this.port = port;
  }

  Node getNode() {
    return node;
  }

  int getPort() {
    return port;
  }
}
```

Then, I've written a management thrift service that does two things:

1) registers a node to a server, returning the port used

2) lists all the services available at the moment

```
typedef i32 int

struct Node {
  1: string hostName,
  2: string serviceName,
}

service ManagementService {
  int NodeRegister(i32 port)
  Node getNodeForService(Node node)
}
```

When NodeRegister is used, the server creates a Map where keys are given by serviceNames and values are NodePorts, and returns the port used by the client.

When getNodeForService is used, it should return a list of services present in the Map registered by a client.

I'm not sure about how to write the implementation of the two methods. I've written this but when I try a test it doesn't work:

```
import org.apache.thrift.TException;

import it.uniud.atta.profiling.thrift.ManagementService;

public class ManagementServiceImpl implements ManagementService.Iface {

  public int NodeRegister(int port) throws TException {
    return port;
  }

  public Node getNodeForService(Node node) throws TException {
    return node;
  }
}
```

I'm pretty sure that this doesn't work the way I want, and also I don't really know where to put the Map code. How could I proceed?

Thanks in advance for any help!

edit: I'm adding the content of my "answer to the question with a question" post. Sorry about it, next time i'll read the rules better!

i actually need help writing the test file. So far i've created a standard thrift server listening on a port, and a thrift client. The code is the following:

```
public class ManagementServiceTest {

public static class Server implements Runnable {

private TServer tserver;

  public void run() {
      try {
           TServerSocket serverTransport = new TServerSocket(7911);

           ManagementService.Processor<ManagementServiceHandler> processor = new      ManagementService.Processor<ManagementServiceHandler>(new ManagementServiceHandler());

           tserver = new TThreadPoolServer(new TThreadPoolServer.Args(serverTransport).
                    processor(processor));
           System.out.println("Starting server on port 7911 ...");
           tserver.serve();
          } catch (TTransportException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
   }

  public void start() {
    new Thread(this).start();
  }

  public void unserve() {
    tserver.stop();
  } 
}

@Test
public void testServerCompletion() {
    Server server = new Server();
    server.start();

    TTransport transport;
    try {

        Thread.sleep(200);
            transport = new TSocket("localhost", 7911);
            TProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(transport);

            ManagementService.Client client = new ManagementService.Client(protocol);
            transport.open();



//          client.getNodes(testNode.hostName, testNode.serviceName);
//          System.out.println("Servizi disponibili: " + testNode.serviceName);
//            
//          for (String key: nodes.keySet()) {
//
//                System.out.println("key : " + key);
//                System.out.println("value : " + nodes.get(key));            

            transport.close();

            server.unserve();   
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure about what do I have to write after the transport.open() line. Right now, I should have a server open on port 7911 and listening, a transport open and an unused client variable that I need to initialize. I want to use the RegisterNode() method and the getNodes() method, but so far all my attempts have been unsuccessfull. i've tried with:

```
Node node1;
node1 = client.RegisterNode(1025);
```

but it returns "The method RegisterNode(Node, int) in the type ManagementService.Client is not applicable for the arguments (String, int)"

So i tried with

```
Node node1;
node1 = client.RegisterNode(node1, 1025);
```

but it returns "Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Node".

I haven't tried with the other method yet, but I guess i'll receive a similar kind of errors.

I'm not sure I've understood how to write a test file... Any hint?

edit: ok, I've managed to solve the problem with this:

```
int port = 0;
Node node1 = new Node();
node1.hostname = "Node 1";
node1.serviceName = "Hello World Service";
port = client.RegisterNode(node1, 1025);
System.out.println("Node hostname: " + node1.hostName + "Node Port Used: " + port);
```

it indeed returns the name of the node and the port used.

Now the second method, getNodes(), presents issues as well. I'm using this:

```
Nodes nodes = new Nodes();
client.getNodes(node1.hostName, node1.serviceName);
System.out.println("Servizi disponibili: " + node1.serviceName);

for (String key: nodes.keySet()) {

  System.out.println("key : " + key);
  System.out.println("value : " + nodes.get(key));    
}
```

but it returns two errors about keySet() and get() methods not being defined for the tyoe Nodes. I'm not sure on how should I proceed...

Comment: What does "*does not work*" mean exactly? If I get a dollar each time someone gives this as the only error description ... so please: What do you expect and what happens instead when you try what?

Comment: Thank you for the answer.Eclipse returns errors in the test file i've written to test the code, at the lines where I call the two methods NodeRegister() and getNodeForService(), saying that the method is undefined for the type ManagementServiceTest (which is the name of the test file).

Comment: actually i've solved that problem but now there is another one. I've written a test server and client file that should register a node named node1 with a serviceName "sum" using port 1025. I added an entry to a Map that uses a string as key (it would be the serviceName, sum), and a NodePort as value. Eclipse tells me that the method put(String, NodePort) in the type Map<String, NodePort> is not applicable for the argument (Node, int). I don't get where is the error...

Comment: `GetNodes()` returns a `Nodes` type (the struct from the IDL below) which contains a member `allNodes`. This `Map<Node,Integer> allNodes` member is actually the map to be iterated. Why is it better to put it into a struct? One word: Flexilibity. This way you can extend the returned data later, if required.

Comment: I would also recommend to have a look at the [Thrift Java tutorial](http://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/java) code. We really have a nice tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would structure the service differently, like so:

```
struct Node {
  1: string hostName,
  2: string serviceName,
}

struct Nodes {
  1: map<Node, i32>  allNodes
}

service ManagementService {
  /** registers a node to a server, returning the port used */
  i32 RegisterNode(1 : Node hostAndService, 2 : i32 preferredPort)

  /** lists all the services available at the moment. 
      Optionally specify host and/or service name to narrow the search */
  Nodes GetNodes(1: string host, 2: string service)
}
```

The map<> code would be in both service routines. In `RegisterNode()` a node is added to the map, in `GetNodes()` the map would be scanned for the values needed.

Sample code, not tested (not even compiled, to be honest):

```
public static class ManagementServiceHandler implements ManagementService.Iface {

    private Map<Node,int> nodes;

    public ManagementServiceHandler() 
    {
        nodes = new Map<Node,int>()
    }

    /**
     * registers a node to a server, returning the port used
     */
    public int RegisterNode(Node hostAndService, int preferredPort) {
        int port = preferredPort;
        // TODO: check whether port can be used
        nodes.Add( hostAndService, port);
        return port;    
    }

    /**
     * lists all the services available at the moment.
     * Optionally specify host and/or service name to narrow the search
     */
    public Nodes GetNodes(String host, String svcname)  {
        var Nodes retval = new Nodes();
        retval.allNodes = new Map<Node,int>();

        for( var node : nodes) {
            if( (host.isEmpty() || (host == node.key.host)) {
                if( (svcname.isEmpty() || (svcname == node.key.serviceName)) {
                    retval.allNodes.add(node)
                }
            }
        }

        return retval;
    }
}
```

Comment: so the implementation of RegisterNode() would be something like: RegisterNode(Node hostAndService, int preferredPort) { Map<Node, int> map = new HashMap<Node, int>; }  ?  I'm not sure how should I implement GetNodes() though...

Comment: Thanks for the sample, I'm looking into it. I had to check a couple things though: 1) var is not present in java so I had to remove it and use the full type name; 2) I had to change all the "add" with "put"). Besides, there is a problem somewhere because eclipse keeps telling me that "The type ManagementServiceHandler must implement the inherited abstract method ManagementService.Iface.getNodes(String, String)", but the method is present. One solution is to make ManagementServiceHandler abstract, the other makes a getNodes() method that returns null. Both seems wrong to me. What should I do?

Comment: Found the problem, it was just the name of the method wrong (GetNodes instead of getNodes). Now I have to look into the iterator because it has a few issues according to eclipse... 1) "key cannot be resolved or is not a field" and 2) "Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable" at the for line "for(Nodes node : nodes)". I need to change something there. Anyway, really thanks for the help!

Comment: You are free to ask, upvote or accept at any time ;-)